# Android CheckBox Increment wrong

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Hi sorry for the simple question but i must be doing something wrong,

I have 12 check box's if a check box is selected a int total needs to be incremented by a fixed value (depending on the box) and displayed in a textView

when i check a box it does not show the value it's suppose to - refurbCost is initalized at 0 in the constructor and is displayed as 0 when no box is selected

when i select  new kitchen is shows as 21300 instead of 3000

what am i doing wrong - p.s i know the code probably isn't great practice im still pretty new at android developing

code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked() ;
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.centralHeating:
            if(checked) {

               refurbCost += 2750;

            }
        case R.id.newKitchen:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 3000;

            }
        case R.id.newBathroom:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 1000 ;

            }
        case R.id.reWire:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 2500;

            }
        case R.id.windowDoors :
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 3000;

            }
        case R.id.stairsBanisters:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 2000;

            }
        case R.id.carpets:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 2000;

            }
        case R.id.garden:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 1000;

            }
        case R.id.wallCeiling:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 1000;

            }
        case R.id.decoration:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 1200;

            }
        case R.id.alarmSys:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 600;

            }
        case R.id.fireSafety:
            if(checked) {
                refurbCost += 4000;

            }
            refurbTotal.setText(""+refurbCost);
    }
```

Comment: maybe you dont decrease value on deselect? and its String.valueOf(refurbCost), and breaks

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic at the moment i am no decreaseing value but even when i have only got 1 item selected it shows the wrong value

Answer (score 5):

You have to `break` after every case statement

e.g.

```
case blabla: doSmth(); break;
```

Comment: ...otherwise the flow falls through all your cases (which sometimes is what you want, but most times it is not).

Comment: @BeginnerJavaDev np, sometimes it helps to check out the tutorials =) [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 1):

break; is missing

```
case R.id.carpets:
        if(checked) {
            refurbCost += 2000;

        }
        break;
```